# How to pass a directive as a parameter to a function in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, directive, swiper.js

I am trying to catch a swiper event and in that event i would like to know where this event is coming from because i have multiple swiper directives in the page.

```
<div [swiper]="SLIDER_CONFIG" (swiperTransitionEnd)="test()" class="swiper-container>
```

I would like to pass the swiper as the method parameter, something like below. But obviously it is not working

```
<div [swiper]="SLIDER_CONFIG" (swiperTransitionEnd)="test(swiper)" class="swiper-container>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass "$event"

```
test($event)
```

Comment: event is undefined in test function

Answer (score 0):

you can mark your directive as exportAs

```
@Directive({
...
exportAs: 'swiper'
})
```

after that you will be able to create template variable witch references the exact instance of a directive and use it however you like

```
 <div [swiper]="..." #mySwiper="swiper" (swiperTransitionEnd)="test(mySwiper)"></div>
```

Comment: I am using an external library, can i do that ?

Comment: you won't be able to modify library directive, however you can extend it with the exportAs if you are using angular 9+. it is not the best solution. is there anything visible in that place of a template that will allow you to fulfill your logic? you can just pass everything to test method

Comment: I am using angular 7, i have posted an answer for a workaround, i have used @ViewChildren and passed an identifier to the test function. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I didn`t find a solution to this but for people who are looking for a workaround i am posting what i did here

I used @ViewChildren to access to multiple swiper directives

```
@ViewChildren(SwiperDirective) swipers: QueryList<SwiperDirective>;
```

I have updated the function call

```
<div [swiper]="SLIDER_CONFIG" (swiperTransitionEnd)="test('First-Swiper')" class="swiper-container>
```

And the test function is

```
test(id:string){
    if(id=="First-Swiper"){
            console.log(this.swipers.first.getIndex(true));
    }else{
            console.log(this.swipers.last.getIndex(true));
    }
}
```